# Tournament with at most three major vertices

Tags: graph-theory

I've encountered a question in my past year papers for finals tomorrow and I need help in this question.

> Let $T$ be a tournament of order $n$ at least $4$, and a vertex $v$ in $T$ is called a major vertex if $s(v) = n-2$. Show that $T$ has at most three major vertices, Also, if $T$ has three major vertices, then $T$ is reducible.

Any help is greatly appreciated! (: Thanks!

EDITED/ They didn't state what is s(v) but I suppose it is the score of the vertex?

Comment: What's a PYP? What's tmrw? What's a qxn? And what does $s(v)$ mean?

Comment: I suppose **s(v)** is the score of the vertex? That's what I have learnt previously.

Comment: Wait a minute --- you're asking the question, and you don't even know what it means? Maybe that's the first thing to find out, then.

Comment: Erm, the question didn't state what does s(v) refers to, but s(v) was stated as score of the vertices in my notes.

Comment: And what is the definition of the score of a vertex?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information given, uhm it's the out degree of a vertex in a directed graph

Comment: If there were 4 major vertices, each of them would have to have beaten (at least) two of the others, which is impossible. Now, what does "reducible" mean?

Answer (score 1):

**Gerry Myerson** has already answered the first part of the question in the comments: if there were $4$ major vertices, each of the four would have to dominate at least two of the other three major vertices, and it’s not hard to check that this is impossible.

Now suppose that $u,v$, and $w$ are major vertices of $T$. To show that $T$ is reducible, we must show that the vertices of $T$ can be partitioned into two non-empty sets, $V$ and $W$, such that each vertex in $V$ dominates each vertex in $W$. What happens if we set $V=\{u,v,w\}$?